# Enrouting request from Internet to my localnetwork

Tags: request, azure-web-app-service, network-programming, settings

I have an API deploy on Azure service apps, and I need a way to connect it throught a PC that has Internet access (But doesn't have a public IP) and is connected to a local network, the idea is to build something that allows me to send requests from the API to different computers in the network, with the minimiun configuration of the PC, I'm having trouble finding documentation or is there an open source solution that allows me to do it?

- The API builds an array of requests to check the state of and application, getting some data requested on demand.
- I'm looking for an implementation that be independent of the API.
- The idea is that the PC that has Internet, works as a bridge, for the requests generated from the API to reach the PC that has the application that needs to be checked.
- The request must come from the API, because there is some configuration and data that can't come from anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

***One approach you can follow is Deploy your Web app API inside a VNET by enabling VNET-Integration, Then Deploy a Virtual Network Gateway and Create Point to Site VPN, Where your Computers can connect to the Azure Site/ Vnet which holds your Web API.*** This way, Even if your Computers lack Public IP, You connect to the Web API. As the authentication will be done via Certificate.

***Azure Point to Site VPN Reference-***
[Connect to a VNet using P2S VPN & multiple authentication types: portal - Azure VPN Gateway | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/howto-point-to-site-multi-auth)

**Create one Virtual Network Gateway:-**

[image]

In order to Generate the Certificate in your local computer and add the content in The Root certificates section. Refer this [Ms Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-certificates-point-to-site) command.

Now, **`Download the VPN Client in your local computers, Run them locally> Visit your local computers's VPN Settings and Connect to the Azure VPN`**:-

[image]

Make sure your Web App is in same VNET as your Virtual network gateway but in another Subnet. As VNET Gateway needs an empty subnet for its deployment.

[image]